# How to load a finetuned sciBERT model in AllenNLP?

Tags: python, allennlp

I have finetuned the SciBERT model on the SciIE dataset. The repository uses AllenNLP to finetune the model. The training is executed as follows:

```
python -m allennlp.run train $CONFIG_FILE  --include-package scibert -s "$@"
```

After a successful training I have a model.tar.gz file as an output that contains weights.th, config.json, and vocabulary folder. I have tried to load it in the allenlp predictor:

```
from allennlp.predictors.predictor import Predictor
predictor = Predictor.from_path("model.tar.gz")
```

But I get the following error:

> ConfigurationError: bert-pretrained not in acceptable choices for
> dataset_reader.token_indexers.bert.type: ['single_id', 'characters',
> 'elmo_characters', 'spacy', 'pretrained_transformer',
> 'pretrained_transformer_mismatched']. You should either use the
> --include-package flag to make sure the correct module is loaded, or use a fully qualified class name in your config file like {"model":
> "my_module.models.MyModel"} to have it imported automatically.

I have never worked with allenNLP, so I am quite lost about what to do.

For reference, this is the part of the config that describer token indexers

```
"token_indexers": {
            "bert": {
                "type": "bert-pretrained",
                "do_lowercase": "false",
                "pretrained_model": "/home/tomaz/neo4j/scibert/model/vocab.txt",
                "use_starting_offsets": true
            }
        }
```

I am using allenlp version

Name: allennlp
Version: 1.2.1

Edit:

I think I have made a lot of progress, I have to use the same version that was used to train the model and I can import the modules like so:

```
from allennlp.predictors.predictor import Predictor
from scibert.models.bert_crf_tagger import *
from scibert.models.bert_text_classifier import *
from scibert.models.dummy_seq2seq import *
from scibert.dataset_readers.classification_dataset_reader import *

predictor = Predictor.from_path("scibert_ner/model.tar.gz")
dataset_reader="classification_dataset_reader")
predictor.predict(
  sentence="Did Uriah honestly think he could beat The Legend of Zelda in under three hours?"
)
```

Now I get an error:

> No default predictor for model type bert_crf_tagger.\nPlease specify a
> predictor explicitly

I know that I can use the `predictor_name` to specify a predictor explicitly, but I haven't got the faintest idea which name to pick that would work

Comment: What repository is this from?

Comment: its from the official scibert: https://github.com/allenai/scibert

Comment: And the training script is available under /scripts/train_allennlp_local.sh

Comment: Feel like I need to include the model somehow that is available at: scibert/models, not exactly sure how to load it in python... is there an example of CLI predict command and the data structure? Very hard to find anything?

Comment: It looks to me like this repo uses an old version of AllenNLP: https://github.com/allenai/scibert/blob/master/requirements.txt#L1. There is no "bert-pretrained" token indexer in the AllenNLP library, but maybe there used to be? I don't know where else that would come from.

Comment: Ok, it seems it is trained on 0.9.0... I have another issue that is
bert_crf_tagger is not a registered name for Model
Help me fix this and I gladly give you 250 + 25 points :)

Comment: and that model is available under scibert/ folder, just no clue how to import it?

Comment: I have made some edits

Comment: There's [someone with that problem](https://github.com/allenai/scibert/issues/102#issue-673470385). Adapting from [this answer](https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/issues/2849#issuecomment-493166329), would say something like «If the model type known then AllenNLP can choose a predictor automatically, but there's no registered predictor of type `bert_crf_tagger` so you'll need to supply one yourself. [Read here for Creating a Predictor](https://docs.allennlp.org/v1.0.0rc4/tutorials/getting_started/predicting_paper_venues/predicting_paper_venues_pt2/#creating-a-predictor).»

Answer (score 3):

I have seen a lot of people having this problem. Upon going through the repository code, I found this to be the easiest way to run the predictions:

```
python -m allennlp.run predict /path/to/saved_model/model.tar.gz /path/to/test.txt\
  --include-package scibert --use-dataset-reader\
  --output-file /path/to/where/you/want/predict.txt\
  --predictor  sentence-tagger --batch-size 16
```

What did I add? The predictor `sentence-tagger`. Once you go through the repository, you would find that the registered predictor is `sentence-tagger`. Although the `DEFAUL_DICT` of the taggers contain `sentence_tagger`. A lot of confusion, right? Tell me!

This answer also saves you from writing a `predictor`.

Comment: can you point to the referenced code? depends on which task you want to do, probably ner classification differs from text classification predictor

Comment: I didn't quite get your question ... But I guess you want me to ask where exactly did I find "sentence-tagger". To answer that, I found it here https://github.com/ibeltagy/allennlp/blob/master/allennlp/predictors/sentence_tagger.py. The predictor for "sentence_tagger" is registered as @Predictor.register('sentence-tagger')